# How do I convert a string that looks like a hex number to an actual hex number in php?

Tags: php, string, hex

I have a string that looks like this `"7a"` and I want to convert it to the hex number 7A.  I have tried using pack and unpack but that is giving me the hex representation for each individual character.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to store that as an integer is [hexdec()](http://us.php.net/hexdec)

```
$num = hexdec( '7A' );
```

Comment: I was going to suggest sscanf, but this is better.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted.  I saw this function earlier but I misunderstood what is did so I thought it wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: I got a float on a large number :-| Consider `intval` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Well a number is a number, it does not depend on the representation. You can get the actual value using [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$number = intval('7a', 16);
```

To convert the number back to a hexadecimal string you can use [`dechex()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php).

Answer (score 0):

This can by try -

```
function strToHex($string)
{
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
{
    $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}
return $hex;
}
```

Comment: This won't work:  You're doing a string catenation of the digits returned by `dechex()`, and the resulting `$hex` value will be the same string that you passed in.  In addition, because `strlen($string)` is in the loop test phrase, it's going to be evaluated on every iteration of the loop.  It would be much better to assign `$nLen=strlen($string)` outside of the loop, then use `$i<$nLen` as the termination test.  This (comment) also says nothing about the evils of using single-character variable names...