# Using a php class object in for each loop

Tags: php, arrays, function, class

I have a class (Color) with a bunch of functions for colour manipulation. I have a separate function to return an array of an images colours.

The colour pallette function has run successfully - outputs the array to $pallette.

Without the loop, i can manually set the $palletteColor var to a hex and the getClosestMatch function returns the closest colour from my reference array. All fine.

When i put this into a loop i don't get the right results - it seems that the return for each loop is the same, so i get 10 identical values back from getClosestMatch.
$palette is from a function outside of the class so still runs as it should. - edit: To clarify - The $pallette array values are not the same - see var_dump below.

I think i may have misunderstood how creating a new class object works or should affect the variables returned. Can anyone shed some light on how the process should work?

EDIT!
Based on the below... When i tested with a hardcoded single value it was an integer (0x003cfe). In the loop i'm adding ('0x'.$palleteColor). Does that make it a string? How can i construct that as an int to test?

```
foreach($palette as $palleteColor) 
 { 

  $color1 = new Color('0x'.$palleteColor);
  $closestmatch = $color1->getClosestMatch($colors);
  echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#$palleteColor;width:2em;'>&nbsp;        
  </td><td>#$palleteColor $closestmatch</td></tr>\n"; 
 }
```

The Class constructor:

```
public function __construct($intColor = null)
    {
        if ($intColor) {
            $this->fromInt($intColor);
        }
    }
```

fromINT function:

```
public function fromInt($intValue)
{
    $this->color = $intValue;

    return $this;
}
```

getClosestMatch function:

```
public function getClosestMatch(array $colors)
{
    $matchDist = 15;
    $matchKey = null;
    foreach($colors as $key => $color) {
        if (false === ($color instanceof Color)) {
            $c = new Color($color);
        }
        $dist = $this->getDistanceLabFrom($c);
        if ($dist < $matchDist) {
            $matchDist = $dist;
            $matchKey = $key;
        }
    }
    echo $dist;
    return $matchKey;
}
```

var_dump of $pallette:

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(6) "ffffff" [1]=> string(6) "ff3333" 
[2]=> string(6) "cc3333" [3]=> string(6) "ff6666" [4]=> string(6) "cc6666" 
[5]=> string(6) "ffcccc" [6]=> string(6) "ffffcc" [7]=> string(6) "ff9999" 
[8]=> string(6) "ff6633" [9]=> int(993333) }
```

Comment: I'd say it's more a problem with what you're passing to the `Color` constructor. Are you sure it expects a string?

Comment: I suggest adding more information. Maybe the code of getClosestMatch, or a var_dump($palette) to see the array contents.

Comment: What are the values in $palette array?

Comment: Added extra info guys

Comment: @Doooder Show fromInt function. Maybe, it incorrectly converts the color value. Print it's result inside __construct function, and compare with result, it is supposed to give.

Comment: @user4035 Strange - The fromINT prints:  
#000000
#0090FF
#D7492D
#57D625 per loop. Now im lost

Comment: Wait, where does `$colors` come from?

Comment: @phil thats my reference array - hardcoded - $colors = array(BLUE => 0x0090ff, RED => 0xd7492d, GREEN => 0x57d625); I assume not a problem as it worked with a single value instead of the loop.

Comment: Edited the description - problem with the $color1 value???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string the looks like a hex number to an actual hex number in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866567/how-do-i-convert-a-string-the-looks-like-a-hex-number-to-an-actual-hex-number-in)

Comment: @Phil perfect! Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved:

Originally tested using hardcoded value -

```
$color1 = new Color(0x003cfe)
```

Looped version used:

```
$color1 = new Color('0x'$palleteColor);
```

That made it a string not an integer
Fixed with:

```
$color1 = new Color(hexdec($palleteColor));
```

Thanks all.